# how to fix elevation of tab layout in android tab fragment

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Please help me how to match the border of tab layout with Appbarlayout and finish the line to make it feel it single. why my tab layout is displaying behind the Appbar.

**This is my Tab layout Screenshot:**

[image]

**This is my Tablayout xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.ahsan.growupwork.ViewProjects">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/random1"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        />



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout and add app:elevation="0dp" in your android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

Answer (score 1):

you have to increase the elevation of your tablayout: `app:elevation="10dp"`to show that it is above the toolbar but if you want to remove it just change the line

`android:elevation="0dp"`

to

`app:elevation="0dp"`

Comment: not working.. Basically i wanna make it like whatsapp ui, tabs and appbar looks like same,

Answer (score 0):

In order to create the effect you want, you have to apply elevation to AppBarLayout and it will fix it.
To use the Toolbar wrap it with AppBarLayout in the code below.

```
     <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="@string/app_name" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```